# ¿Cual sería la forma más limpia de hacer un custom validation message en sailsjs?

Tags: javascript, sailsjs

Según la [documentación](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?custom-validation-messages) de sailsjs, este no posee aún la posibilidad de crear *custom validation messages* para las operaciones de **create** and **update**, por lo que quisiera saber si alguien ha desarrollado otra forma de manejar estos mensajes y personalizarlos sin utilizar [sails-hook-validation](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-validation)

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes usar [sails-model-new](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-model-new) pero eso es sólo limitar la solución a una instancia en específico. Hay alguna razón por la que no quieras usar la solución recomendada por la documentación de sails? Instalar un módulo que lleva ya algún tiempo de desarrollo parece ser la forma más razonable de resolver el problema.

Comment: Entiendo, lo que pasa es que estaba haciendo el tutorial de [Sailscast](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/) en donde proponen manejar los errores de formularios a traves de variables de sesion, pero entiendo que por ahora, mientras no haya un recurso nativo del framework, lo mejor sera usar **sails-hook-validation**. Gracias por la aclaratoria :)

Answer (score 1):

Hola creo que una mejor forma de abordar el problema es hacer la validación en el controller y de esto se habla un poco en la documentación de sailsjs en `When to use validation`, la primera aproximación seria crear una función que valide cada campo y al final devuelva un array o json con los mensajes o códigos de error que usted defina y esto lo puede mostrar perfectamente como un mensaje en su html, otra camino es usar algún modulo de npm que ya brinde las capacidades de validar. Tambien existen librerías de jquery que le permite validar desde el html, pero al usarla es igual importante validar en el controlador

Un ejemplo podría ser que necesite saber si el email se envió correctamente

```
 if ( !_.isString( req.param('email') ) ) {
  return res.badRequest(); //o "mi mensaje"
}
```

y aquí se debería tener varias validaciones en cuenta como que no me llegue un vacio o una cadena '', y que el formato del email sea correcto, por esto es mejor usar un modulo ya construido como [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) o cualquier otro que le parezca útil.